# WSO2 mailto transport. Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587

Tags: wso2, mailto, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I tried to send email using wso2 mail to transport but got this error

```
[2021-01-08 09:46:48,133] [EI-Core]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2021-01-08 09:48:55,485] [EI-Core] ERROR - MailTransportSender Error creating mail message or sending it to the configured server
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMail(MailTransportSender.java:520)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMessage(MailTransportSender.java:182)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 13 more
[2021-01-08 09:48:55,493] [EI-Core] ERROR - MailTransportSender Error generating mail message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error creating mail message or sending it to the configured server
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.handleException(AbstractTransportSender.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMail(MailTransportSender.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMessage(MailTransportSender.java:182)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMail(MailTransportSender.java:520)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 13 more
[2021-01-08 09:48:55,498] [EI-Core]  INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=ee60111e2cfd2756410df0877d7ff1cd768edb7f3087b9f9] Error generating mail message
```

here axist2 setting

```
<transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">sendmail</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">***</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">sendmail@gmail.com</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

EmailTemplate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template name="EmailTemplate" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="subject"/>
    <parameter name="toAddress"/>
    <sequence>
        <property expression="$func:subject" name="Subject" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>        
        <property name="messageType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <property expression="fn:concat('mailto:',$ctx:email)" name="emailEP" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <header expression="get-property('emailEP')" name="To" scope="default"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <default/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </sequence>
</template>
```

I use activemq to trigered the message, here the email proxy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="UserMgtCreateEmailSender" startOnLoad="true" transports="jms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="emailSubject" scope="default" type="STRING" value="Test Email Subject"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.email)" name="email" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <xslt key="conf:xsl/email-body-xslt.xslt"/>
            <call-template target="EmailTemplate">
                <with-param name="subject" value="{$ctx:emailSubject}"/>
            </call-template>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">sendemail.user</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules xmlns="">
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/json</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>
```

and this is the email-body-xslt.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <p>Service Name: Test Proxy</p>
            <p>Execution success</p>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The message i send to queue is the target email

```
{
  "email":"username@gmail.com"
}
```

This code is work for several times but suddently got error like that. i dont know what cause. please help. I'm new with wso2.

Comment: Are you certain your server is able to reach the internet? This doesn't look to have anything to do with WSO2 or your configuration, it looks like it cannot connect with the server -> `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)`

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of trouble with the SMTP configuration as well. I think what is currently wrong is the user. When I tried to configure it the user had to also be the full email.

```
<transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">sendmail@gmail.com</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">***</parameter>
       <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">sendmail@gmail.com</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

Let me know if that works for you otherwise it might but some firewall issue.